# How to generate avro files from JSON

Tags: java, json, avro

I have a very simple JSON file and an .avsc file:

`twitter.json`:

```
{
    "username": "test"
}
```

`twitter.avsc`:

```
{
    "name": "MyClass",
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "com.acme.avro",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "username",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm converting the json file to an avro file with the following command, but when I try to read the file in IntelliJ's parquet/avro viewer it says that it's not valid avro.

`java -jar avro-tools-1.10.0.jar fromjson --schema-file twitter.avsc twitter.json > twitter.avro`

Any idea why this doesn't work?